# How can I bulk change the sort of my images?

Tags: magento-1.9, image-preview

When I bulk upload images, all the images arranged according to the second images. How can I bulk update the images displayed based on the first image?

[image]

Comment: how did you do?

Comment: import excel sheet

Comment: more detail please, what is the template you used?

Comment: this is my template

Comment: http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/53327.html

Comment: my error is, actually i import my products images through csv as a bulk import,  wrongly my second view of my products images taken as a thumbnail image, so, how can i bulk changes