# How can i increased selected items default QTY count in products page

Tags: product, default-values

I need to set up selected products default count is what i suggest. How can i set my default minimum count.

```
I need to set defauly Qty = 5 for elected products
```

[image]

Comment: Didu set this in your product Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart: 5

Comment: no, how can i set this

Comment: Make sure one think bro, i just want to increased QTY for only few products like 10 products, not for all products,,

Comment: Ok open any product goto inventory section there you will find this option and set Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart: 5

Comment: @Kothari : Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest way that can help you to archive what you want.

[image: magento minimum qty product]

Another way, you can override this function in catalog product view

`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::getProductDefaultQty`

and update default qty for any product according its id.

good luck!!!

Comment: help me @ http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142191/how-can-i-bulk-change-sort-of-my-image